# Bootstrap 4 Container with half reaching to edge

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achieve a `.container` with two halves.

The left half acts normally as a `.col-6`, and the right half stretches all the way to the right side of the screen, as if it were a `.col-6` inside of a `.container-fluid`.

So, similiar to this...

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Curabitur ipsum nisl, volutpat non vulputate in, aliquet id ipsum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin dolor velit, tristique eget leo eu.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- this needs to stretch out all the way to the right -->
        <p>Aliquam dapibus consequat diam, a luctus nisi fermentum eu. Proin at enim at dolor convallis vestibulum. Etiam tempor vel enim sed sodales. Vestibulum rhoncus odio felis.</p>
        <p>Sed sodales turpis posuere vel. Proin at scelerisque elit, vitae feugiat lectus. Ut nisl dui, pulvinar at fringilla vitae, bibendum imperdiet mi. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I hope that makes sense, thanks in advance.

Comment: And what's your question exactly? The code works fine and the right part does stretch out all the way to the remaining half of the page. And if you're wondering why isn't it overflowing the body of the webpage, its because that's what bootstrap is. And the row consists of 12 grid columns,  6 is occupied that is 50% by your first div and the rest is occupied by the next one.

Comment: @Highdef - thanks for your response. My questions is that the left column stays within the `container` , but the right column does not. A `container-fluid` would make the columns go directly to the edge, and I was trying to work out a way for the right column to stretch all the way out, while the left column stays boxed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Bootstrap 4 has an out-of-the-box solution for such a layout, however it can be implemented easily with a couple of additional style sets.

In the solution below I approach this with a top level `.container-fluid` tag, as that covers the entire viewport width. Then for mimicking a “half container” in the left column, I have created the `.container-half` class. This is based on the `.container` class but the width of it is set to the half of the original. Also, in order to demonstrate how responsivity can be taken care of, the `.container-half-md-left` serves as an example.

Note: the css below serves as an example with manually crafted media queries. In production I would compile the entire set from scss.

Check this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dferenc/pen/dZxpbz).

HTML

```
<section>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 px-0" style="background-color: LightCyan;">
                <div class="container container-half container-half-md-left h-100" style="background-color: LightBlue;">
                    <p>Curabitur ipsum nisl, volutpat non vulputate in, aliquet id ipsum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin dolor velit, tristique eget leo eu.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: LightSteelBlue;">
                <p>Aliquam dapibus consequat diam, a luctus nisi fermentum eu. Proin at enim at dolor convallis vestibulum. Etiam tempor vel enim sed sodales. Vestibulum rhoncus odio felis.</p>
                <p>Sed sodales turpis posuere vel. Proin at scelerisque elit, vitae feugiat lectus. Ut nisl dui, pulvinar at fringilla vitae, bibendum imperdiet mi. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .container-half { max-width: calc(540px / 2); }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container-half { max-width: calc(720px / 2); }
    .container-half-md-left { margin-right: 0; }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container-half { max-width: calc(960px / 2); }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container-half { max-width: calc(1140px / 2); }
}
```